# Question about a conclusion from the Cauchy Integration Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I did just learn about the Cauchy Integration for Discs:

If $f$ is holomorphic in $S$, let $D:=D_r(c)$ be a disc such that $D$ and $\partial D$ are both in $S$. Then for every $z \in D$:
$f(z)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\partial D} \frac {f( \zeta )}{\zeta -z} d \zeta$

Now if one chooses $c$ to be the center of the disc with the parametrization $c+re^{i \phi}$ we get the "Mean Value Property"

$f(c)=\frac{1}{2 \pi } \int_{0}^{2 \pi}  f(c+re^{i \phi }) d \phi$

Considering the estimation lemma ( $|\int_{\gamma} f dz| \leq  max_{t \in [a,b]}|f(\gamma(t))| L(\gamma)$ ) we get:

(1) $|f(c)| \leq max_{t \in [0, 2\pi]}|f(c+re^{i \phi})|$

Now I am confused on how to get to the inequality (1)

My calculations:

$|f(c)|=|\frac{1}{2 \pi } \int_{0}^{2 \pi}  f(c+re^{i \phi }) d \phi| \leq \frac{1}{2 \pi } max_{\phi \in [0, 2 \pi]} |f(c+re^{i \phi})| \underset{=2 \pi r}{L(\gamma)}=r 
 (max_{\phi \in [0, 2 \pi]} |f(c+re^{i \phi})|) $

As you can see I got an "$r$" to much.
I would be thankful if someone could explain me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align*}|f(c)|=\left|\frac{1}{2 \pi } \int_{0}^{2 \pi}  f(c+re^{i \phi }) \,d\ \phi\right| \leq \frac{1}{2 \pi } \max_{\phi \in [0, 2 \pi]} |f(c+re^{i \phi})|(2\pi-0)=
 \max_{\phi \in [0, 2 \pi]} |f(c+re^{i \phi})|\end{align*} $$
When you introduce the value of parametrization on the integral you have no longer a contour integral but a definite one, so you bound with the length of integral interval, not the length of the contour line.